# Django overriding default ModelForm error messages not working

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to django and I know there are many stack overflow questions and answers related with this topic, but none of the solutions seems to work for me. I am trying to override django's default error messages.
I tried these to name a few of the solutions I tried.

```py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
     error_messages = {
                'first_name': {
                    'required': _("First name is required."),
                },
            }
```

Also tried this

```py
class MyRequest(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        blank=False,
        error_messages={
            'blank': 'my required msg..',
        }
    )
```

Is there any thing I need to do on the template side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the field like this

```
`first_name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required':_("First name is required.")})`
```

NB: if the error is for the condition required, adding a message for blank or null won't cut it. also in your form's Meta, don't forget to add your model.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

(In general the required property is assigned to form field by default)

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # we want to add or overwrite this field
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="First Name", required=True,
                                 help_text="Required: Enter your first name")

    class Meta:
        # If the form is related to some model, add the model name here
        model = ModelNameGoesHere
```